# Having issues with php mail() form

Tags: php, html, email

I am very new to php and can't quite figure out what is wrong with this. Any help would be appreciated.  Also, it would be beneficial to have a way to test whether it is me or just my hosting service that will not allow me to send the email. So, if there is a way that I could do that please let me know.

```
 <?php
session_start();
 $visitor_email = '';
$user_message = '';

//Validates the email address that the user entered
function spamcheck($field)
  {
  // Sanitize e-mail address
$field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate e-mail address
if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
  return TRUE;
}
else
{
return FALSE;
}
}


//When user clicks 'submit'
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$user_message = $_POST['message'];
//if user entered email address
if (isset($_POST['email']))
    {
    // Check if email address is valid
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($visitor_email);
        if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
            {
            echo "Invalid input";
            }
        else
            {
            $to = "example@yahoo.com";
            $subject="Customer Feedback";
            $from = $visitor_email;
            $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';

            $body = "A patron submitted the contact form:\n".
            "Email: $visitor_email \n".
            "Message: \n ".
            "$user_message\n".
            "IP: $ip\n";    

            $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);

            header('Location: home.html');
            }
 }
 }
?>

<form id="feedBackForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post">
                <fieldset id="personal">
                    <legend>Your Information</legend>
                        <label for="email">Contact Email:  </label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($visitor_email) ?>'/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="text">
                    <legend>Message:</legend>
                        <label for="message"></label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message"><?php echo htmlentities($user_message) ?></textarea>
                </fieldset><p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                </p>
                </form>
```

I have tried a couple different iterations and this is just where I happen to be at the moment

Comment: What's the actual problem? What doesn't work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: This `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` you're telling it "if it is **not** set, ....." you want `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- You should post an answer.

Comment: What happens seems to be nothing. The page just reloads.

Comment: @Fulmetal5 If the current answers don't solve your problem, you should start with checking the return value of `mail()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` you're telling it "if it is **not** set, ....."

you want `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

(telling it now, if it **is set**, execute everything inside the conditional statement)

**N.B.:** The `!` is the logical [`not`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) operator.

Posted as requested by [`jeroen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914806/having-issues-with-php-mail-form#comment33191440_21914806)

**Edit**:

I tested your code after setting the correct conditional statement (removing the logical [`not`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) operator), and the mail was successfully sent and received. Therefore, you need to check if your server is set up to handle mail, or check your SPAM as well as server logs.

Comment: That helped and let code pass through and it even redirected the page correctly, but no email was sent.

Comment: Are you running your code from your own computer (localhost) or on a hosted service? See my edit, I tested this and result was OK. @Fulmetal5

Comment: Is it a free service? If so, chances are that `mail()` is not available. I've seen that happen many times before, where people would ask the same question, only to turn out that the service they were using was free and mail was not available. @Fulmetal5 Plus, check your SPAM if mail is available.

Comment: It is indeed free. I thought that that might be the problem.  They did not have it explicitly stated anywhere on the website that mail through php was not supported, which is very aggravating.

Comment: Which company are you with? @Fulmetal5 If it's GoDaddy, apparently GoDaddy does not process mail if the recipient is Gmail, Yahoo, or other Free email service etc.

Comment: It was in the spam folder of my email. Thanks!  Is there anyway to avoid it being sent to the spam folder?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, to avoid it going to spam, is a very complex subject. There are too many variables at stake. The server you're on now, may have been blacklisted or something to that effect, and everything being processed through it, will be treated as Spam. Since the server I am on (paid service), the mail was not treated as Spam, because of its good rating. @Fulmetal5

Comment: Ok, that should be fine. I was actually testing this on a free server because it is meant to replace one that is already on a visited paid server site.

Comment: I also use a few free hosting services for DB work and some mail, nothing extensive, because testing on another server (DB) is safer in case something goes terribly wrong. So, I suggest you try out a few more. @Fulmetal5 Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First I think you have to change

`if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` to `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

because it look like a bug

Comment: OK, it redirected me correctly but the email wasn't sent. So that makes me think that it passed through all of the checks and something else is wrong.